# Failed to resolve: com.android.support:appcompat-v7:31.0.0

Tags: android, android-support-library, jitsi

I'm trying to add Jitsi meet sdk to my android project.

i've implementation('org.jitsi.react:jitsi-meet-sdk:5.0.2') { transitive = true }
and

maven { url 'https://github.com/jitsi/jitsi-maven-repository/raw/master/releases' }

but it gives error:
Failed to resolve: com.github.MatrixFrog:android-scalablevideoview:v1.0.4-Packet

i'm try fix that by add maven jitpack.io but it still give me error:

Failed to resolve: com.android.support:appcompat-v7:31.0.0 in spite of implement
how can i fix this? please help me

my settings.gradle:

pluginManagement {

```
repositories {
    gradlePluginPortal()
    google()
    mavenCentral()
}
```

}

dependencyResolutionManagement {

```
repositoriesMode.set(RepositoriesMode.FAIL_ON_PROJECT_REPOS)
repositories {
    google()
    mavenCentral()
    maven { url 'https://maven.google.com'}
    maven { url 'https://www.jitpack.io' }
    maven { url 'https://github.com/jitsi/jitsi-maven-repository/raw/master/releases' }
}
```

}

build.gradle(:app)

plugins {

```
id 'com.android.application'
id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android'
id 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

}

android {

```
compileSdk 31
buildToolsVersion "31.0.0"
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "kma.longhoang.kmaelearning"
    minSdk 24
    targetSdk 31
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}
buildFeatures {
    viewBinding true
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
compileOptions {
    sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
}
kotlinOptions {
    jvmTarget = '1.8'
}
```

}

dependencies {

```
implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.7.0'
implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.4.1'
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.6.0'
implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.3'
implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging-ktx:23.0.4'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore-ktx:24.1.2'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.3'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.4.0'
implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:29.1.0')
implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-extensions:2.2.0'
implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.9.0'
implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-scalars:2.9.0'
implementation 'com.makeramen:roundedimageview:2.3.0'
implementation 'androidx.swiperefreshlayout:swiperefreshlayout:1.1.0'
implementation 'com.intuit.sdp:sdp-android:1.0.6'
implementation 'com.intuit.ssp:ssp-android:1.0.6'
implementation('org.jitsi.react:jitsi-meet-sdk:5.0.2') { transitive = true }
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:31.0.0'
```

}

Comment: V31 does NOT exist

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My suggestion is implement `com.android.support:appcompat-v7:31.0.0` and enable jetifire by adding the line below to your `gradle.properties` file

```
android.enableJetifier=true
```

Comment: it work! my problem has resolve. thank you

Comment: Also works with `implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.4.2'`

Comment: It is wrong. V31 does not exist

Answer (score 0):

Try this I have got same issue with Jitsi It was resolved with this

```
 dependencyResolutionManagement {
    
    repositoriesMode.set(RepositoriesMode.FAIL_ON_PROJECT_REPOS)
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
        maven { url 'https://maven.google.com'}
        maven { url 'https://www.jitpack.io' }
        maven { url 'https://github.com/jitsi/jitsi-maven-repository/raw/master/releases' }

ADD THIS code--------------------
  //noinspection JcenterRepositoryObsolete
        jcenter() {
            content {

                includeModule("com.yqritc", "android-scalablevideoview")
            }
        }
---------------------till Here------------
    }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The latest version of support liberties is v28. The version v31 doesn't exist.

Just **remove** the dependency:

```
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:31.0.0'
```